# Is there another word for 'listening' to an answer?

Tags: verbs

We 'listen' when we're being told something. Is there another verb for 'listening' to an answer to a question we asked?

Is 'receiving' an appropriate word for it? It sounds reasonable in the context of the answer being in a written format

> "I have received an answer"

But it doesn't sound right if the answer happens to be in an audible format (think two people face to face, instead of the answer being a recording)

P.S.: I'm not looking for 'hear'. I'm asking if there's a verb that carries the same weight as 'listen', but applies specifically to the situation of being given an answer.

Comment: 'Listening' focuses on the behaviour (and, behind that, the attitude) of the 'audience' (listener/s, reader/s – note that we can broaden the meaning to those not in earshot [Those people at the BBC just aren't listening to me]) – while 'receiving' focuses on coming into possession of the information (in your mind, in a letter ...). 'Pay attention to' is synonymous with 'listen to'.

Comment: You could say you "***heard*** her answer" (which simply means "*received audibly*", but lacks the sense of *having understood*, as Edwin says).

Comment: "Did you get an answer from Jane about foo?" "Yes, I received her response yesterday via voicemail." (More than likely, though, "She called me and gave me an answer yesterday.")

Comment: *You have gotten my answer.*

Comment: "I got the answer from her." Anything else would be quite rarely used as it's almost always who provided the answer, not who received it.

Comment: @SrJoven Yes, the emphasis always seems to be on the one providing the answer. Actually, I wondered if there was a word for when you tell someone to "listen" to your answer.

Comment: @lo0pin I'm **hearing** a reluctance to use the word *listening* on your part.

Comment: telling someone to do something is an *order* or *command* or perhaps *instruct*. But you're not going to easily find an answer where someone is going to have a word for "Listen up! The answer you seek is:"

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I use the words 'Ask', 'Tell', 'Answer', 'Listen' as section headers for a site that lets you do the same. I need a name for a section where you can view the answers. That made me wonder if there was another word for "listen" that's used in the context of answering.

Comment: The answer was absorbed or assimilated or comprehended or accepted or taken or received or gathered or pondered or recognized.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of a word or short phrase that combines the concepts of "hear" and "understand" without context, but you can reply conversationally to an answer in the following ways: "I see." "I follow." "I get it." It's interesting that the metaphor "I see" conveys understanding better than "I hear you" does.

Comment: @DanBron Also 'hear' is quite a different verb to 'listen'. One can hear without listening and one can listen without hearing. What the OP needs is another verb which means much the same as 'listen'. 'Receiving' does not work at all, as it seems equivalent to 'hearing'. The only thing I can think of is 'paying attention'. Edwin has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @Ws2, I'm not sure. Before a judge renders a final decision, he "***hears** the legal arguments*" from both plaintiff and defendant, which means much more than passively accepting audio signals: it means the judge both *pays attention to* and *intellectually considers* their arguments, *without* (yet) *passing judgement*. Same reason the phrase "*I **hear** you*" is so popular in [non-violent communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonviolent_Communication).

Comment: @WS2: In fact, I just looked it up, and one of the definitions of "*to hear*" is "*to listen to with attention: **heed**, **attend***", and another, perhaps more pertinent, is  "*to **gain knowledge** of by hearing*".

Comment: @DanBron The judge example is a specialised legal use of the word 'hear'. It happens at a 'hearing' of the court. Besides, even a judge has to start out by listening, but neither he nor the jury give any consideration until they have 'heard' the evidence. It is insufficient for them simply to have listened. 'Listening' is something that one does actively. 'Hearing' is something that happens, often aided by actively listening. Posted before I read your second comment.

Comment: @WS2, look again at the dictionary definitions I referenced (neither of which is given in a legal context -- nor indeed by a legal dictionary).

Comment: @Dan Bron OED says:**Listen** The action or an act of listening; a spell of listening or attentive hearing. Also listen-out (after look-out). Chiefly in phr. on or upon the listen : in the act of listening. **Hear -intransitive** To perceive, or have the sensation of, sound; to possess or exercise the faculty of audition, of which the specific organ is the ear. The proper verb to express this faculty or function. -**transitive**. To perceive (sound, or something that emits or causes sound); to have cognizance of by means of the ear or auditory sense.

Comment: @WS2, if only the OED will satisfy you, then **hear me**: "*To exercise the auditory function intentionally; to give ear, **hearken**, **listen***" and "*trans. **To listen to (a person or thing) with attention or understanding**; to give ear to, **hearken** to; to **give audience** to.*". And of course it also has an entry for the ***imperative hear*** ("*hear me!*", "*hear! hear!*"), which wouldn't make sense if "*hear*" only meant "*passively allow sounds into one's auditory channels*".

Comment: @DanBron Was that the OED? Or was it Oxford Dictionaries - on line?

Comment: @WS2, Quoting the definition of "*listen*" doesn't change the definition of "*hear*" nor the fact that the OED gives "*listen*" and "*hearken*" and as actual, literal, *synonyms* of "*hear*". The definitions I just quoted literally appear in the OED. They are what "*hear*" (in *addition* to your usage) **means**.

Comment: @WS2 Not ODO, literal OED. The [entry is here](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85048) if you have a subscription. (Though the ODO and all other dictionaries include similar definitions for "*hear*" as well, because that's what "*hear*" means [yes, among other things, as always]).

Comment: @DanBron Yes. I was quoting from meanings 1 and 2. You have quoted meanings 4a and 4b. but note that the most recent example they have of 4a is from 1702. 4b relates to such uses as 'hear me out', which I accept is an active verb, a bit like 'listen'.   Meanings 5, 6, 7, deal with the judicial meaning we discussed and similar other cases.  Hence I am still strongly of the view that 'hearing' is fundamentally passive. The deaf cannot hear.

Comment: @WA2 In another thread, a user is complaining my OED citation is invalid because it's too early (#1), and here you are complaining another is invalid because it's too late (#4). I think you both miss the point of a dictionary:  the definition exists ***because the word has that meaning***.  I gave two current examples already (a judicial *hearing* and the nonjudgemental but active psychosocial usage "I *hear* you) and I could give an endless number more, but fortunately I don't need to, ***because we have dictionaries***.

Comment: @WS2 In re: the deaf, they cannot literally, physically *listen to you*,  either. But they can, figuratively, metaphorically, "*hear* you out", and "*listen* to what you have to say "; and fortunately (but not surprisingly) dictionaries have entries for those metaphorical meanings as well.  Because that's the purpose of dictionaries. And that's what "*hear*" means, whether you like it or not or agree or not.

Comment: @DanBron I accept that there are senses of 'hear' which imply an active process, and they are found in OED meanings 4 *et seq*. (Meaning 3 deals with the 'I heard he got married' cases, which are not directly related to physical hearing.) But I cannot concede so far as the mainstream use of the word is concerned.

Comment: @WS2, I **hear** what you're saying, but I do not agree (and this sentence would literally be impossible unless *hear* had an active, interpretative, attentive sense; and no living, breathing, contemporary, *mainstream* person reading this will misunderstand what I'm saying).

Comment: @DanBron But I do agree with you. They are meanings 4a and 4b of the OED.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with any statement about the OED; I was disagreeing with and  (simultaneously) debunking your statement about "*mainstream use*".

Comment: This is now getting autoflagged. Perhaps everyone can continue this disccusion in chat, then just post an executive summary here and purge the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "***accept***" someone's answer, just as you can "*receive*" a package.

There are two competing connotations to "*accepting*" an answer, however: in the first, you simply "*take receipt of it*", without passing judgement; in the second, you are contrasting what you did to "*rejecting*" the answer: you both "*took receipt*" and "*approved*" of it.

For examples of the first connotation (*take receipt **without** passing judgment or approving*), which seems to be what you're seeking:

***OED***:

> To take or receive (*something offered*) willingly.

[***Macmillan***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/accept):

> Take something offered; (*trans*) to take something that someone gives you

[***Oxford Dictionaries Online***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/accept):

> Consent to receive (*a thing offered*)

[***Collins***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/accept):

> (*trans*) To take (*what is offered or given*); receive, esp. willingly

[***Merriam-Webster***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accept):

> (*a*) To receive willingly and 
>   (*b*)  To be able (or designed) to take or hold (*something applied or added*)

***Google Definition***:

> Consent to receive (*a thing offered*).
>
> *"He **accepted** a pen from George"*
>
> *synonyms: **receive**, take, get, gain, obtain*

Comment: I did consider "accept". As you say, when asking someone to "accept" an answer, we're asking the person to both receive it and approve of it, without a choice.

Comment: I think you missed a subtlety in my post: accept can mean *either* take receipt ***without*** passing judgment either way, **or** take receipt **and** (simultaneously) approve.

Comment: My bad! I haven't seen the word "accept" used in situations where one is expected to receive an answer, without passing a judgement. Could you give me an example?

Comment: No problem. See my updated answer with the "receive without judgement" definition from several dictionaries (always the first definition).

Comment: Sounds acceptable! It's not quite the same as replacing 'listening' in "listening to an answer". 'Accepting' sounds a bit passive. I'll "accept" your answer though, with the connotation that indicates approval :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Lots of words and metaphors in this example that mean *listen*, including *receive*, *attend*/*make one's ear attentive*, *incline one's heart to understanding*

...if you *receive* my words and *treasure up* my commandments with you, *making your ear attentive* to wisdom and *inclining your heart to understanding*; yes, if you call out for insight and raise your voice for understanding, if you seek it like silver and search for it as for hidden treasures, then you will understand... [Proverbs 2:1-5 ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+2%3A1-5&version=ESV)

1b) Again *receive*/*receive in one's heart*

...Son of man, all my words that I shall speak to you *receive in your heart*... Ezekiel 3:10 ESV

2) Another is *pay attention*

*Pay attention* to what you hear... Mark 4:2-4 ESV

3) Aother is *give ear*

*Give ear*, O heavens, and I will speak... Deuteronomy 32:1-2 ESV

...*give ear* to his commandments... Exodus 15:26 ESV

3b) Here is again *give ear* and *attend*

Who among you will *give ear* to this, will *attend*... Isaiah 42:23 ESV

4) some more variations are *incline*/*incline one's ear* and *apply one's heart*

*Incline your ear*, and hear the words of the wise, and *apply your heart*... Proverbs 22:17-18 ESV

Incline your ear, and come to me...*  Isaiah 55:2-3 ESV

...he *inclined* to me and heard my cry...  Psalm 40:1-3 ESV

5) more variations are *awaken one's ear* and *open one's ear*; also *be taught*

...he *awakens my ear* to hear as those who are *taught*. The Lord God has *opened my ear*... Isaiah 50:4-5 ESV

...he opens the ears of men and terrifies them with warnings.

6) this includes *give ear*, *attend*, *understand* and *take it to heart*

Who among you will *give ear* to this, will *attend* ... but he did not *understand*; it burned him up, but he did not *take it to heart*.  Isaiah 42:23-25 ESV

7) another is *accept*/*accept instruction*/*be instructed*

...*accept instruction*, that you may gain wisdom in the future  Proverbs 19:20 ESV

8) similar to above is *be guided*

Where there is no *guidance*, a people falls...  Proverbs 11:14 ESV

9) hark/heark and harken/hearken are archaic words for *listen*

10) more modern words that can be used for *listen* include *consider*, *heed*, *mind*

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you are speaking to the person from whom you are awaiting an answer, I would say "Yes, I heard you." or "Yes, I understood that.". In cases such as "Did you receive a response from Jane?", you might say "Yes, I did get her response, and it was quite clear."

Comment: I'm looking for a verb, not a phrase or a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can say, I'm still processing - you listened to the words, heard the information - but haven't assimilated it yet.

Or, for just a verb:  "I'm focused on your answer"  which is implies listening with intent, not listening while playing on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

> [***pay attention***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pay_attention)
>   (idiomatic, intransitive) To attend; to be attentive; to focus one's attention.
>   <sub>Wiktionary</sub>

For example when talking to a child who is playing a game while I'm trying to tell them something, I might tell them to

> *Pay attention* when I'm talking to you.

Or when someone stops talking because it looks like the person they're talking to is not listening, they might say

> Keep going, I am actually *paying attention.*